# Writing first part of my thesis

Tags: titles, fontsize

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{eucal} 
\usepackage{eufrak} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\title{\ttitle} 
\linespread{1.375}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\begin{document}

\centerline{ \textbf{Universit\`{a} degli studi di xxxx}}

\vspace{4cm} 

\centerline{\textbf{Ph.D  thesis}}

\vspace{2cm} 
\centerline{ \textbf{XXVII CICLO}}
\vspace{2cm} 
\bigskip
\centerline{ \textbf{Italy is a beautiful country Applications}}
\vspace{4cm} 
 \centerline{\textbf{NSA}} 
\vspace{2cm} 
\centerline{\textbf{Academic years : 2011-2014 }}
\newpage

\chapter*{Declaration}

This thesis has been submitted to the university of xxx in fullfilment of the
requirements for the Doctoral degree in Economics, Applied Mathematics and
Operational Research.

\chapter*{Dedication}
To my friends
\newpage
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}

\author{Author Name}
\date{Day Month Year}

\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoftables

\end{document}
```

I'm writing my doctoral thesis and this is the cover above. Normally as you can see the size is 12 for the whole thesis but  i need a help for increasing to 14 the caracter size  of the title which is "Italy is a beautiful country Applications". Please can you tell me how can i increase the size of the title to 14? and also the name of my university  which is " Universit`{a} delgi studi  di xxx? at the same size(14).

Further question: How can i remove the number of pages? As you see it start from the first page. I want to number( with number 1) it starting from the page of contents(which is here page 5). I want to get the page number 1 on the page related to table of contents.
thanks

Comment: `\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont`

Comment: @Sigur i need to change only the character size of the title not whole framework. The code you provide me is increasing the caracter size of the thesis from the title to the rest of the text. Please i need to increase the caracter of the title so some specific part.

Comment: Use braces: `{\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont new size here}\normalsize`

Comment: @Sigur `\normalsize` is redundant; instead there should be `\par` before `}`.

Comment: Could you make your example a bit more **minimal**? See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what you need (and don't need).

Comment: @egreg, I agree. I just wanted to make sure that OP is understanding what is happening inside the braces.

Comment: May be you want to use simply `\large` (14.4pt when the norrmal font is 12pt).

Comment: @Fran Nah. It is likely an institutional requirement and they'll insist it be 14 and not 14.4. Of course, any *reasonable* system would accept `\large` but we are dealing with thesis formatting requirements and are well beyond the reach of reason. ;)

Comment: @Sigur But the `\par` is required else the baselineskip will be wrong when the paragraph ends as it will have reverted to that set by `\normalsize`.

Answer (score 2):

This uses the `titlepage` environment which is really a better option here. I've replaced `\centerline` with `\centering`. Since you need an additional `\par` to get the font sizing and since the fonts have changed size for two lines, you may need to readjust your spacing here.

I've used `\thispagestyle{empty}` on the pre-chapters before the table of contents. `\pagenumbering{arabic}` starts the numbering from 1. I use `\clearpage` rather than `\newpage` to avoid accidentally creating unwanted blank pages. In some cases, nothing is required - new chapters start new pages anyway.

I've also made your example a bit more minimal although it could  be reduced further.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\title{\ttitle}
\linespread{1.375}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \centering\bfseries
    \fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont
    Universit\`{a} degli studi di xxxx

    \normalsize
    \vspace{4cm}

    Ph.D  thesis

    \vspace{2cm}
    XXVII CICLO
    \vspace{2cm}
    \bigskip\par
    \fontsize{14pt}{16pt}\selectfont
    Italy is a beautiful country Applications\par
    \normalsize
    \vspace{4cm}
    NSA
    \vspace{2cm}\par
    Academic years : 2011-2014
  \end{titlepage}

  \chapter*{Declaration}\thispagestyle{empty}

This thesis has been submitted to the university of xxx in fulfilment of the
requirements for the Doctoral degree in Economics, Applied Mathematics and
Operational Research.

\chapter*{Dedication}\thispagestyle{empty}
To my friends

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}\thispagestyle{empty}

\author{Author Name}
\date{Day Month Year}

\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listoftables

\end{document}
```

[image: overview of results]

Comment: @HarishKumar About the `\normalsize` - why is it better to use `{}` than font switches? (Apart from less typing.) The `\fontsize... \normalsize` has the advantage of significantly greater transparency.

Comment: i found your answers above the most useful particularly @cfr user. Thanks